# How to create a secondary connection to another DB in case of failure of primary DB

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two databases 192.168.1.82 (Master) and 192.168.1.83 (Slave) how can I configure laravel to reconnect to another database in case of failure of master DB.

I only now that I can define a second DB in .env file but, but I don't know how to verify and execute a condition in case of a DB failure.

Comment: I don't think the failover should be handled at the application level. The easiest options are likely to repoint the database DNS record or to use a proxy.

Comment: I think it's help full https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1037